# How to prevent navigation from Navigator.pushNamed... and display bottom modal?

Tags: flutter

If I have a MaterialApp with `routes` defined, upon navigation a function is triggered.

For some routes (protected ones) I'd like to prevent that navigation and open Modal Bottom Sheet, with `showModalBottomSheet`

I tried to do it like this:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Flutter App',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/profile': (context) {
          if (signedIn) {
            return PopScreen();
          } else {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                    color: Color(0xFF737373),
                    child: FractionallySizedBox(
                        heightFactor: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(radius),
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(radius))),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )));
              },
            );
          }
        },
      },
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

With the above the router doesn't reach the `/profile` route, which is fine, but then I get an error `The builder for route returned null. The builders must never return null`.

How Can I prevent navigation?

Is there a better way of doing it? Tutorials I found seem to suggest to add the `if logged in` on a button and redirect from there, but it seems like this part should be central inside of the router.

Comment: show more code for showModalBottomSheet(...);

Comment: @griffins
I added more description. I have also found the ModalRoute, which by the description is exactly what I'd like to do by I can't find an example of how to use it :(
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html

Comment: I think you need to add return before showModalBottomSheet or return simple scaffold then in onInit function show the dialog or action sheet

Answer (score 0):

firstly I think you need to add return before showModalBottomSheet or return simple scaffold then in onInit function show the dialog or action sheet

if this not work try

create a service or helper function to navigate to profile and use it in entire app

```
class NavigationService {

  static navigateToProfile(Context context) {...}


}
```

check for isLogged and if true navigate to route. if false ShowDialog() or Open action sheet for that

Comment: Adding the helper would help, but if I forget to use it, interface would become unstable. I'd like it to happen on the router level. In React native I used to use the https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/custom-routers, return null from the navigation and then open a modal

Comment: When returning anything from the function, the navigation still is triggered. I'd like to prevent it.